# why is fetch/ajax not working in a ruby rails app on mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, fetch

i have a rails app that am using fetch to send data to my database,

```
    function like(x, y){
        fetch('/post_likes', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({post_id: x, profile_id: y}),
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            }
        })
         .catch(err => console.error(err));;
    };
```

it works fine on desktop and laptops, but wont work on android or os cellphones, how can i debug

Comment: Hi, could you edit your question with the logs of the request that does not work?

Comment: am not getting any errors from aws console logs,